# Quebra de linha em um arquivo .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como quebrar a linha ao passar meus dados para um arquivo .txt?

O código que estou usando para abrir, escrever e fechar o .txt são esses:

```
arquivo = open("arquivo.txt", "a", newline="")
arquivo.write("%s;" % nome_critico)
arquivo.close()
```

O que eu estou querendo é que todos os dados fiquem dessa maneira:

[image]

E não desse jeito: 
[image]

Meu código completo está em baixo:
https://repl.it/Jbl1/0

Comment: No último valor impresso, você não pode colocar `%s\n`?

Comment: O problema de fazer isso é que o \n vai junto com o arquivo .txt. Ex: "Max;6.000;\n"

Comment: Assim funcionou para mim: https://repl.it/Jbl1/3. Basicamente coloquei o `file.write("\n")` ao final do `if`.

Comment: @KennethAnderson, vc retira facilment esse `\n'` com rstrip, exemplo: `'test string\n'.rstrip()`

Comment: Ou vc pode usar `splitlines()` para retirar as quebras de linhas, quando lê o arquivo. Veja na edição da resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quebra de linha com o escape apropriado para isso, basta adicionar `'\n'` no final da string. No exemplo abaixo leio as strings de uma lista e adiciono a quebra de linha quando gravo no arquivo:

```
arquivo = open("arquivo.txt", "a", newline="")
persons = ['Jose antonio de oliveira; jose@fake.com', 
           'Ana Fake da Silva; ana@fake.net']

for p in persons:
    arquivo.write(p+'\n')
arquivo.close()
```

**Mostrando o conteudo do arquivo com o comando `cat` (Linux):**

```
cat arquivo.txt
Jose antonio de oliveira; jose@fake.com
Ana Fake da Silva; ana@fake.net
```

> **Editada**
>   Depois de ler os comentários com mais atenção, achei que deveria complementar a resposta.

### Lendo o arquivo:

**Com `readlines()`:**

```
lines = open('arquivo.txt','r').readlines()
print (lines) 
['Jose antonio de oliveira; jose@fake.com\n', 'Ana Fake da Silva; ana@fake.net\n']
```

**Com `splitlines()`:**

```
lines = open('arquivo.txt','r').read().splitlines()
print (lines)
['Jose antonio de oliveira; jose@fake.com', 'Ana Fake da Silva; ana@fake.net']
```

Veja que `splitlines()`, retira "automágicamente" o escape para quebra de linnha.